# Overflow Does Not Work

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code for the #Wall div:

```
#Wall {
z-index:0;   
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 0px;
margin-left: -952px;
width: 1920px;
height: 1200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This forms a wallpaper advertising image which is clickable. Unfortunately, the overflow function does not work and browser places a horizontal scroll for the right part of the image. How to fix this and hide the part of the image which should be seen only on higher resolution screens?

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Comment: You need some container `div` where is `#Wall` pasted.

Comment: we are missing some elements like HTML structure, but my first though would be that ```overflow``` should be on the parent of ```#Wall``` If you intend to hide a part of the ```#Wall``` div.

Comment: Why are you positioning the div 50% from the left, then setting a negative margin left of 952px?  Also, try setting the overflow on the parent container

Comment: @JustinBreiland He's using the left/margin to center his wall since he positioned absolutely, but you are right in saying overflow needs to be set on the parent rather the child.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding the overflow code in the body {}, too.
Thanks indeed.